# Should I join a pool?

Tags: mining-pools, ethereum

I've configured the large (8x) GPU image on AWS at 2.60/hour. I ran it goes few hours after setup and mined nothing.

This was my first foray into mining.

Given this setup, am I better placed to join a pool? And what pool should I join? (Some pools reward the biggest contributor and others payout shares.)

Comment: What mining algorithm does Ethereum use? Is GPU mining viable for Ethereum?

Comment: You should first look at your hash rate and estimate your average rate of earning, to see if there is any chance for this to be profitable given your costs.  My guess is no, in which case using a pool will only make it worse.

Answer (score 2):

You are unlikely to collect rewards consistently (or at all) solo mining with that hashrate. You should join a pool to smooth out your expected return, unless you are okay with the posibility of earning nothing for long periods of time (or are a very lucky person).